# GRUB2: error: disk `(hd0,)' not found

Tags: boot, grub2, lfs

I had almost finished Linux From Scratch ; However, when I tried to started the new LFS system. GRUB couldn't launch the system:

> error: disk `(hd0,)' not found.

Then I used `grub> ls`
Output: `(hd0) (hd0, gpt4) (hd0, gpt3) (hd0, gpt2) (hd0, gpt1)`
I followed the instructions without anything too special, except for that I used GRUB with UEFI because my host system had been using UEFI and GPT.
Here's the partition table:

- /dev/sda GPT
- /dev/sda1: 512MB in size. EFI system partition. FAT32
- /dev/sda2: 16GB in size. Linux swap. [SWAP]
- /dev/sda3: 64GB in size. Linux x86_64 root. ext4. Host system.
- /dev/sda4: 32GB in size. Linux x86_64 root. ext4. LFS system.
  I install grub in sda1. The file tree in sda1 is like:

```
.
├── config-5.16.9
├── EFI
│   └── LFS
│       └── grubx64.efi
├── grub
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── grub.cfg
│   ├── grubenv
│   ├── i386-pc
│   ├── locale
│   │   ├── ast.mo
│   │   ├── ca.mo
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── zh_TW.mo
│   └── x86_64-efi
│       ├── acpi.mod
│       ├── ...
│       └── zstd.mod
├── System.map-5.16.9
└── vmlinuz-5.16.9-lfs-11.1-systemd
```

And the content of `grub.cfg`:

```
set default=0
set timeout=5
insmod part_gpt
insmod vfat # I've tried fat here.  
set root=(hd0) #I've tried (hd0,gpt1), (hd0,gpt4), (hd0,1) .etc here.  

if loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2; then
        set gfxmode=auto
        insmod all_video
        terminal_output gfxterm
fi

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Linux 5.16.9-lfs-11.1"{
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.9-lfs-11.1 root=/dev/sda4 ro
}

menuentry "Firmware Setup"{
        fwsetup
}
```

I mainly followed these references:

- [BLFS.GRUB](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/stable-systemd/postlfs/grub-setup.html)
- [LFS.GRUB](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable-systemd/chapter10/grub.html)

Also, I had set to use UEFI without CSM support or legacy.
More details:

- GRUB version 2.06
- LFS version 11.1-systemd
- Linux kernel version 5.16.9
- Secure boot disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, GRUB relies on UEFI services to access the ESP, so unless you have firmware support for `ext4`, GRUB will only be able to read FAT32. It would be able to read `ext4` after `insmod ext2`, but to do that, it needs to read `ext2.mod` first.

To gain more functionality, GRUB needs to be able to load its modules, which are apparently located in the `/grub/x86_64-efi` directory on `/dev/sda1`. But to do that, GRUB needs two important variables set correctly: `root` and `prefix`.

In your case, you want `set root=(hd0,gpt1)`, assuming that you have only one disk. If you have multiple disks, predicting the correct `hdN` number can be tricky, and that's why modern distributions usually prefer to use the `search --fs-uuid --set=root <UUID-of-the-filesystem>` syntax instead of a direct `set root=`.

The `prefix` should be set to `(hd0,gpt1)/grub`. Use the `set` command with no parameters in the GRUB prompt to view the current state of the GRUB variables.

GRUB can only focus on one filesystem at a time, so if you are mounting `/dev/sda1` as `/boot`, then while GRUB has `root` set to `(hd0,gpt1)`, it will see `/boot` as `/`. So you should omit `/boot` from all paths that refer to `sda1`.

If you need to load something from the ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sda4`, you would do it as a three-step operation:

1. `insmod ext2` while `root` and `prefix` are still set as described above
2. `set root=(hd0,gpt4)` to switch GRUB focus to the LFS root filesystem
3. Load whatever you have to, keeping in mind that `/boot` is just an empty directory on `sda4`. The Linux kernel will use it later as a mount point for `/dev/sda1`, but that does not help GRUB at all.

So the lines you need to correct in your `grub.cfg` are:

```
...
#set root=(hd0)    # not just the disk, but the partition/filesystem GRUB will focus on
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
...
#if loadfont /boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2; then   # GRUB will see /boot as /
if loadfont /grub/fonts/unicode.pf2; then
...
#       linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.9-lfs-11.1 root=/dev/sda4 ro  # same here, also fix the kernel filename
        linux /vmlinuz-5.16.9-lfs-11.1-systemd root=/dev/sda4 ro
...
```

The `/boot/grub/i386-pc` directory is going to be utterly useless on a UEFI system; feel free to remove it.

The `/boot/grub/fonts/unicode.pf2` file doesn't seem to currently exist on `sda1`. But since you can apparently get GRUB in text mode without it, you can live without it.